# How do we achieve that our application also can move to SDCard?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I created one application, its working fine. I want to support my application in sdcard also. That means, users can move the application to sdcard from internal memory.

How can i achieve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can give the option to your applications. You must assign below code to your `manifest` file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="auto"
... >
```

This will be enable that option for your application.

Refer below links -

[App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html)

[Manifest Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

But, the important thing is it supports only from 2.2 (Froyo) and above.

Comment: i think OP question is something else.

Comment: @hotveryspicy OP question means?

Comment: @Spk AndroidVsIphone is asking something else, he is asking that he want to give choice to user either to install it in internal or external, but in your case it is predefined fixed that application will store only in sdcard

Comment: @SpK still it same what i meant.